# Cannot display images from geoserver into the web application

Tags: web-mapping

I cannot load any map in the web application
Arches web app (https://arches.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  I am working with, at the beginning I thought it was problem with the ports so I opened some ports to see if that was the problem, but I got many errors so I reset the firewall as it was previously.

But I am still without images displayed in the web application. I have pointed to GeoServer using this two links adding them as sources, I can preview them in GeoServer.

```
{"type": "raster", 
 "tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/eamena_kmz/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eamena_kmz:Alg_Tun&bbox=-9.0%2C19.0%2C12.0%2C38.0&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/jpeg&transparent=true"], 
 "tileSize": 256}
```

This one loaded the layer but filling the whole canvas instead of just the area it was supposed to fill obtaining this

[image]:

I have tried changing the format and other characteristic but I didn't get any different.

The other image I am loading it won't display nothing just the map base, by using this code and the changing it to different options:

{"type": "raster",
"tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/eamena_kmz/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eamena_kmz:areas_poly_2&bbox=-3.71526980482206%2C-4.59012629161883%2C7.56371986222731%2C8.48909299655568&width=662&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=aapplication/json;type=geojson&transparent=true"],
"tileSize": 512}

Thanks in advance for your help I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely issue is that your URLs are wrong - for example if you expect a Raster layer, requesting a JSON output is probably wrong as that will return a vector text representation of your data (and application is spelt with one A at the beginning).

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/eamena_kmz/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eamena_kmz:areas_poly_2&bbox=-3.71526980482206%2C-4.59012629161883%2C7.56371986222731%2C8.48909299655568&width=662&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=aapplication/json;type=geojson&transparent=true
```

Also for a tileSize of 512 you specifying a width of 662 and a height of 768 which is unlikely to be helpful.

Maybe you should read the [https://github.com/legiongis/arches4-geo-examples[enter](https://github.com/legiongis/arches4-geo-examples%5Benter) link description here][1](https://github.com/legiongis/arches4-geo-examples) or find out how a [WMS server works](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html).

Looking at the manual tells me the magic json file should look like:

```
{
    "type": "raster",
    "layers": [{
        "id": "wms-layer2",
        "type": "raster",
        "minzoom": 0,
        "maxzoom": 22
     }],
    "config": {
      "provider":
      {
        "name": "url template", 
        "template": "https://db.legiongis.com/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=crnha:confedmaps_full&styles=&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&format=image/png&bbox=$xmin,$ymin,$xmax,$ymax&width=$width&height=$height&bboxSR=3857&size=$width,$height&imageSR=3857&f=image"
      }
    }
}
```

So there are a number of specific parameters that you must fill in and some that must be left for the program to fill in (though most GIS programs fill these in for you).

For example you must specify the layer name, style name and projection you want to use, but the mapping engine will fill in the bounding box, size of the image. And to be honest I have no clue what or why you would specify `imageSR=3857&f=image` for.